# Want to run script file using system call in android NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I want to run script file on android Shell using Native C program.

I tried using `system` function but it's not working.

```
result = system("sh ./test.sh");

LOGD("result is %d", result);
```

system command returns 0 means its not executed script file successfully.

test.sh contains

```
echo "test...."
```

Android NDK application could not print `test....` when this system call runs.

Even any script can not be started using system call. i checked more than 10 different scripts.

test.sh have `777` permissions

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it should be result = system("sh ./test.sh"); say the dot before the blackslash

Comment: @blackbelt this command directly works so why its not working in system call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i got the answer of this Question on Different post.

[Run Shell Script file On Android Embedded Device using System function in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909995/run-shell-script-file-on-android-embedded-device-using-system-function-in-androi)

thanks to all for Help

Answer (score 2):

where is 'sh'? and what is your '.' current directory when the application runs? try:

`result = system("/system/bin/sh /full/path/to/test.sh");`

Comment: test.sh is on my current direcory...I tired above command also but its not working

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/system, if system() returns 0, then the command worked, otherwise it would be -1. Maybe the program runs but its output is not displayed for some reason? Try with a shell script that writes to a file ("echo test >> test1") and see if afterwards test1 exists...

Comment: I also tried this Option but its not working. i write one file using shell script using above command. but file not exits after using this

Comment: What if script wants input ? How to handle such situation?

Comment: @BRUCE Maybe an ugly workaround, but you could write that input to a temporary file and run a wrapper .sh that contains the line "test.sh < file".