# Run Shell Script file On Android Embedded Device using System function in Android NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

All

Here i want to run .sh file via system call in android NDK.

I able to run `cp,rm` command via system call. but sh command is not working via system call.

I also installed busy-box on android.I am using below code.I set all permission on `test.sh`.

Code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>

#define LOG_TAG "Demo"

#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)


void Java_com_ndkdemo_NDKdemoActivity_systemcall(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj) {

    int result;

    result = system("cp /mnt/sdcard/test /Download");

    LOGD("result is cp %d", result);

    result = system("sh ./test.sh");

    LOGD("result of test.sh is %d", result);

}
```

Output :

```
 result is cp 0.
 result of test.sh is 0.
```

Here i am getting 0 in `system("sh ./test.sh");` but not started the `test.sh` script.

cant get output `"Hi"` on console.

test.sh contains

```
#!/system/bin/
echo "Hi"
```

If i am executing direct command on prompt than its working fine and its given output `"Hi"` on console.

Please Help me to figure out this issue.

Thanks

Comment: also, FYI: your first line should point to the script you want to run, so should be set to `#!/system/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you expecting to see the "echo"? By default, android sends stdout to /dev/null.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#stdout) you can redirect stdout and stderr to the log (so it will show up in logcat) using the following commands:

```
$ adb shell stop
$ adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true
$ adb shell start
```

Now you may see your echo in `adb logcat`.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply , But without this i cant able to run shell script?

Comment: You can run the shell script without doing the stdio redirect, but the echo is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `sh -c /full/path/to/test.sh`

Comment: OK. Note that using `echo` might not be the best way to test this, try using `touch` or something that creates a file. It's not exactly clear where the stdout of shells you start from NDK are redirected.